# How to dynamically add a page break if printing reaches a second page

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I'm having an issue with my HTML product sheet.

When there are enough products selected on the page to amount to a second page, the top of the second page gets smudged with the new product that has its styling all messed up.

CSS i've tried this far

```
 @media print{

        #packingPrint {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
```

`div` that contains the information needing to be printed.

```
  <div style="page-break-after: always;">
        <!--END: pagebreak-->
        <section id="packingPrint" style="font-family:verdana,helvetica,sans-serif" ;>
            <!------ START: Confirmation ------>
            <!--START: order_details-->
            <div class="customerInfoBlock" style="border-bottom: solid;border-width: 1px;">
                <!--start customer info block-->
                <div class="left-col">
                    <!--START: invoicelogo-->
                    <div class="invoice-logo"><img src="../[invoicelogo]" alt="[company]" /></div>
                    <!--END: invoicelogo-->

                </div>
                <!--end customer info block-->
                <!--start invoice info block-->
                <div class="right-col">
                    <div class="orderNumber">
                        <div class="label">Order Number #:</div>
                        <div class="text">[invoicenum_prefix][invoicenum]
                            <!--START: shipmentsuffix--><span style="display:none;">-[shipment_suffix]</span>
                            <!--END: shipmentsuffix-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                         <div class="label">Order Date:</div>
                    <div class="text">[odate_month]/[odate_day]/[odate_year]</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end invoice info block-->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="billingBlock">
                <!--start billing block-->
                <div class="left-col">
                    <p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: underline;"><strong>SHIPPING ADDRESS</strong></p>

                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipzip]</p>

                    <div class="spacer"></div>

                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipfirstname] [oshiplastname]</p>
                    <!--START: oshipcompany-->
                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipcompany]</p>
                    <!--END: oshipcompany-->
                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipaddress]</p>
                    <!--START: oshipaddress2-->
                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipaddress2]</p>
                    <!--END: oshipaddress2-->
                    <p style="font-size:18px">[oshipcity]</p>





                </div>
                <!--end billing block-->
                <!--start shipping block-->
                <div class="right-col" style="max-width: 300px">




                    <div class="deliveryBox">
                        <div class="text"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><img src="/assets/images/shipping1.png" width="40" height="40" style="padding-right:5px; margin-bottom: -10px;">[oshipmethod]</span> </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spacer1">
                        <div class="text"><img src="/assets/images/Weight1.png" width="25" height="25" style="padding-right:5px;">Weight:[totalweight]kgs</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spacer1">
                        <div class="text">
                            <p style="font-size:15px"> <img src="/assets/images/email1.png" width="25" height="25" style="padding-right:5px;">[oemail]</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spacer1">
                        <div class="text">
                            <p style="font-size:15px"><img src="/assets/images/phone1.png" width="25" height="25" style="padding-right:5px;">[ophone]</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                </div>
                <!--end shipping block-->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shippingInfoBlock" style="width:100%;">
                <!--START: shipping_info-->

                <div class="invoiceTable">
                    <div class="titles2" style="padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">

                        <div class="invoice-qty">Qty</div>

                        <div class="invoice-loc">Loc</div>
                        <div class="invoice-items">Items</div>
                         <div class="invoice-ais">2loc</div>
                        <div class="invoice-cus">Stock</div>
                        <div class="invoice-id">Item ID</div>


                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--START: items-->
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: solid;border-width: 1px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">
                        <div class="invoice-qty">[numitems]</div>
                        <div class="invoice-loc">[warehouse_location]</div>
                        <div class="invoice-items">[itemname]</div>
                        <!--START: warehouse_location-->


                         <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_aisle]</div>
                        <div class="invoice-cus" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_custom]</div>
                        <div class="invoice-id" style="text-align:center;">[id]</div>



                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <!--END: warehouse_location-->
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!--END: items-->
                <div class="orderDetailsBlock">
                    <div class="left-col">
                        <!--START: ocomment-->
                        <div class="ocomment" >
                            <strong>Order Comments:</strong>
                            <p class="oCommenting"><strong><span class="commentsOrder" style="color: #ff0000;">[ocomment]</span></strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <!--END: ocomment-->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <p id="imagePick"><img src="https://www.plasticpipeshop.co.uk/assets/images/Picked.png" alt="Picked By" align="right" width="250" height="150" /> </p>

            <!------ END: Confirmation ------>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Picture of the issue [showing the top of the second, and bottom of the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVAyJ.png)

Comment: In your CSS sample, you are missing either a dot or hash before "packingPrint" to indicate class or ID. Is this the same in your full CSS?

Comment: No my full CSS is correct sorry for the mistake.

Comment: In that case you can edit your post using the grey "edit" link under where it lists the tags - it should be roughly level with your profile card

Comment: Ah okay, sorry new to the site and javascript. It should be updated now